# ant replaceregexp, matching with variable/property

Tags: xml, regex, ant

This should be a common problem but I can't figure out how to do it, hoping for some guidance here.

**The problem:**

I need to replace some, but not all application versions in a set of XML configuration files (weblogic config.xml files) using ant (ant-contrib is also ok to use).

I have a list of applications that should have new version set, and what version they should have and I have the configuration files where I need to to the replace.

**The path I took so far:**

I created a macro that takes three arguments; application name, application version and config file.

This will be invoked from a loop.

Here is what I have right now:

```
<macrodef name="update-template-config-file">
  <attribute name="application-name" />
  <attribute name="application-version" />
  <attribute name="config-file-name" />

  <sequential>

    <local name="match-string"/>
    <local name="replace-string"/>
    <property name="match-string" value="@{application-name}#[0-9](\.[0-9])*"/>
    <property name="replace-string" value="@{application-name}#@{application-version}"/>

    <echo>match ${match-string} replace: ${replace-string} in @{config-file-name}</echo>

    <replaceregexp file="@{config-file-name}"
      match="${match-string}"
      replace="${replace-string}"
      byline="true"/>
  </sequential>

</macrodef>
```

So the issue with this is that the match part of replaceregexp is interpretated as a regular expression (correctly), and I'm wondering if there is a way to use value of 'match-string' property rather than the name of it.

**Workaround:**

From ant script, create a new ant script by echoing replacement instructions per loop, then invoke the created ant file to execute the replacements.

**For completeness, target where macro is called**

```
<target name="update-template-config-files">
  <for param="config-file">
     <path>
       <fileset dir="${RP_CONTENT_ROOT_DIR}/domain_templates" includes="**/config.xml"/>
     </path>
    <sequential>
      <for param="application-file">
        <path>
          <fileset dir="${STAGE_ROOT}/applications" includes="*.*"/>
        </path>
        <sequential>
          <local name="filename"/>
          <basename property="filename" file="@{application-file}"/>
          <update-template-config-file application-name="${filename}" application-version="5.1.0.3.0" config-file-name="@{config-file}" />
        </sequential>
      </for>
    </sequential>
  </for>
</target>
```

Comment: Does the echo work correctly?

Comment: Hi,Yes it does, here is a sample after replacing real application name & path: [echo] match some_application.ear#[0-9](\.[0-9])* replace: some_application.ear#5.1.0.3.0 in /some/path/config/config.xml

Comment: I'm writing an ant task meanwhile.

Comment: Actually I found a mistake, forgot to remove suffix (eg .ear). Will try that.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in my script, forgot to remove the suffix from the application names.

Thanks vio1331 for having me look at the echo line one more time.

Find below updated snippet that works (but only for ear files)

```
<target name="update-template-config-files">
  <for param="config-file">
     <path>
       <fileset dir="${RP_CONTENT_ROOT_DIR}/domain_templates" includes="**/config.xml"/>
     </path>
    <sequential>
      <for param="application-file">
        <path>
          <fileset dir="${STAGE_ROOT}/wlng/applications" includes="*.ear"/>
        </path>
        <sequential>
        <local name="filename"/>
        <basename property="filename" file="@{application-file}" suffix=".ear"/>
        <update-template-config-file application-name="${filename}" application-version="5.1.0.3.0" config-file-name="@{config-file}" />
        </sequential>
      </for>
    </sequential>
  </for>
</target>
```